# How to set default value for form fields?

Tags: magento-1

I have an admin form field(textbox),

```
$fieldset->addField('ajax_time_interval', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('dealroom')->__('Page Refresh Time Interval'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'ajax_time_interval',
      ));
```

I need to set a default value for this text field. I tried, setting `'value'     => '120',` in it. But its not working.

```
$fieldset->addField('ajax_time_interval', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('dealroom')->__('Page Refresh Time Interval'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'ajax_time_interval',
          'value'     => '120', 
      ));
```

How to set a defalt value in that field?

Comment: Check that it's not a browser cache issue. I has this serveral times, especially in Firefox, which is caching the latest values.

Comment: Have you verified you are not doing setValues on the form after field definition? If you do and object used (or array) is empty, then all values are cleared.

Comment: @Peter- Yess! It was the issue...! Thanks, I was using `setValues`..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the textfield itself displayed?
The setting `'value' => '120'` seems correct to me.

Comment: yes. it is displayed. :(

Comment: @Anna Völkl: you are right but if `addValues()` method is used afterwards those values are being rewritten.

Answer (score 12):

Your problem is that values you set with `addField()` method are then overwritten with `addValues()` method which tries to set up a form fields values when form is used for editing existing entities or error occurred during submission.

Here is a workaround. Most likely you are getting values with a protected method like this:

```
protected function _getFormData()
{
    $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData();

    if (!$data && Mage::registry('current_osmm_project')->getData()) {
        $data = Mage::registry('current_osmm_project')->getData();
    }

    return (array) $data;
}
```

So inside of your `_prepareForm()` method you replace:

```
$form->addValues($this->_getFormData());
```

with:

```
$_data = $this->__getFormData();
if (!empty($_data)) {
    $form->addValues($_data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everybody for spending your valuable time and effort. I was Using `setValues()` after `addfields`. So the default values were being cleared.

I overcome it by providing an `if` loop, such as:

```
if (Mage::registry('dealroom_data')->getAjaxTimeInterval() < 0 || Mage::registry('dealroom_data')->getAjaxTimeInterval() == "") {
    Mage::registry('dealroom_data')->setAjaxTimeInterval(120);
}
```

**120** is my default time here.

Comment: please see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking and are working on 1.9 and have the below

```
if($model){
    $form->setValues($model->getData());
}
```

You can do the following without having to edit your existing data, just above that code place:

```
if($model->getData('fieldName') == ""){
    $model->setData('fieldName', "yourValue");
}
```

Of course you can check isset and such but here is the basic version of setting defaults.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$data['ajax_time_interval'] = 120;
```

where `$data` is an array of form fields.

```
$data['{field_name}'] = '{field_name}';
```

Answer (score 0):

=> You can add **'default'** attribute in form fields. Like this :

```
        $fieldset->addField('ajax_time_interval', 'text', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('dealroom')->__('Page Refresh Time Interval'),
      'class'     => 'required-entry',
      'required'  => true,
      'name'      => 'ajax_time_interval',
      'default'     => '120', 
  ));
```

Comment: It's Not working