# Magento Custom Module set default value to Textfield

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

I am working on custom module. I want to set default value to text field but failed. I have visited some links for solution but didnt working. 
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702983/how-to-set-default-value-in-dropdown-of-admin-grid-form-in-magento) and [Link2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-to-set-default-value-for-form-fields)

```
$this->setForm($form);
$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('home_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('home')->__('Section Information')));
$fieldset->addField('section_name', 'text', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('home')->__('Section Name'),
      'required'  => false,
      'name'      => 'section_name',
      'value' => 'asdf',
));
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that somewhere in the code you call `$form->setValues($somethingHere)`.
Replace that line with:

```
$form->addValues(array('section_name'=> 'asdf'));
$form->addValues($somethingHere);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `default` attribute for this. Like,

```
$this->setForm($form);
$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('home_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('home')->__('Section Information')));
$fieldset->addField('section_name', 'text', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('home')->__('Section Name'),
      'required'  => false,
      'name'      => 'section_name',
      "default" => "asdf"
));
```

Comment: default attribute didn't work in my case.